# Implementing Generic Find<T> Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, generics, dbcontext

I'm implementing generics for Add, Remove, and Find, because I'm implementing multi-tenancy that gives me access to IQueryables from the database, as opposed to DbSets.

How Add was implemented:

Code before:

```
interest = db.Interests.Add(new Interest()) // Interests is dbSet
```

Code after:

```
interest = db.Add(new Interest()) // Interests is dbSet

// in db class
public T Add<T>(T item) where T : class, ITenantData
    {
        var set = _appContext.Set<T>();
            return set.Add(item);
    }
```

This works.  Now I'm trying to do the same thing for Find, but because I'm working with an Id and not a Typed parameter, I'm a bit stuck.

Code before:

```
var aptitude = db.Aptitudes.Find(interest.AptitudeId);  // Aptitudes is a DbSet
```

Code after:

```
var aptitude = db.Find(interest.AptitudeId); // how to identify type?
```

I can't do this:

```
var aptitude = db.Aptitudes.Find(interest.AptitudeId);
```

Because Aptitudes is now an IQueryable.

So this is currently failing:

```
public T Find<T>(T query) where T : class, ITenantData
    {
        var set = _mentorContext.Set<T>();
        return set.Find(query);
    }
```

Because the type isn't identified - I get :

> The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'App.Context.TenantContext.Find(T)'    Service.cs

I'm a bit new to generics, any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you do `db.Aptitudes.Find(interest.AptitudeId);`?  That seems like the best option by far.  Why does it being an `IQueryable` mean you can't use it?

Comment: @Servy - because Aptitudes is now an IQueryable - per this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758080/dbset-modelbuilder-and-ef-navigation-properties/19759042#comment29364347_19759042

Comment: Still not seeing the problem.  Calling `Find` doesn't change the type of `Aptitudes`, nor would it being an `IQueryable` mean you couldn't find that item using the methods available through LINQ.  Still not seeing a problem here.

Comment: Ah - I'm trying to use Find() over Where() for performance reasons.

Comment: So then change the type of the method to accept a set, rather than an IQueryable, still not seeing a problem here.

Comment: `public T Find<T>(params object[] keyComponents) where T : class, ITenantData` -- note that `.Find` only works for the primary key. For candidate keys or other filters, you need `.Where` or some other LINQ extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this with extension methods.

```
public IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class, ITenantData
{
    return _mentorContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
}
```

...meanwhile in another class...

```
public static MentorContextExtensions
{
    public static InterestEntity ByAptitudeId(
        this IQueryable<InterestEntity> queryable, 
        int aptitudeId)
    {
        return queryable.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AptitudeId == aptitudeId);
    }
}
```

...usage against `IQueryable<T>`...

```
db.Query<InterestEntity>().ByAptitudeId(interest.AptitudeId);
```

The example above returns a `SingleOrDefault`, but you could just as easily return sets (pre-filtered `IQueryables` or `IEnumerables`) using `.Where`, `bool`s using `.Any`, etc.

To maintain usage of the `.Find` (by primary key) method on the `IDbSet`, you can do this:

```
public T Find<T>(params object[] keyComponents) where T : class, ITenantData
{
    return _mentorContext.Set<T>().Find(keyComponents);
}
```

...and use it like this...

```
var aptitude = db.Find<Aptitude>(interest.AptitudeId);
```

... that said, using `.Find` may only be faster when you are doing inserts, updates, deletes with the entity, in some kind of mutation code. `.Find` will always keep the entity attached to the context, which is what you want when you need to mutate the data. However you cannot invoke `.AsNoTracking()` on it because it returns a single entity. If you only need the entity to read its properties or for display purposes, `.AsNoTracking` will keep the entire entity graph (the entity and its navigation / collection properties) detached from the context, which may be faster than using `.Find`. If you later want to use the same entity instance in mutation code, you can attach it to the context at that time.

Comment: WOW.  This is incredible.  Thanks you :)